# Change the length of a line wrt the center

Tags: inkscape

How do I change the length of a line with respect to the center? I wish to reduce the length of a line symmetrically from both ends while keeping the center in place.

Comment: I serendipitously figured it out myself. If you hold shift while changing the length, it changes the length with respect to the center.

Comment: You can make this an answer and mark it correct for future users to find easily :)

Comment: I can, and will, after 12 hours. I cannot answer my own question within 12 hours of posting the question, if I have a reputation<10. :)

Comment: Fair enough! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I serendipitously figured it out myself. If you hold shift while changing the length, it changes the length with respect to the center.